# Duplicate plugins change Original's Content

Tags: buildfire

When Duplicating plugins on the Buildfire Dashboard. Then modifying content in the said duplicate plugin, content in the Original plugin is altered as well. I have learned the hard way, and I have been notified on a couple of other circumstances as well.

Comment: Hey Case, obviously if this was a systemic issue the entire platform wouldnt work. Can you share which data storage are you using? Data Store, User Data, Public Data, Your own db ..etc

Comment: @Daniel_Madain This was happening in DataStore within the normal Buildfire folder plugin.

Comment: That is very odd. Datastore is heavily segmented so data-bleeding wouldn't happen. I also just tested it on my own test app. I would say contact customer support and give them details about your appid and plugin. They should be able to help you on a private forum